# Is this insect a pest?

Tags: pest-control

I have seen many of these insects lately. Usually just on the outside of the house - around the front door or the patio - but sometimes also inside.

Is this some kind of cockroach or other pest? Can they cause any harm?

The location is Germany, the province of Baden-Württemberg.

[image: picture of a brown insect]

Comment: Often bug identification is done in the gardening stack exchange.  Perhaps it should be migrated there.

Comment: Can you describe roughly where you found this bug? Like the nearest major city or geographic region?

Comment: @Keeta I am asking specifically if I should take steps to protect my home from that critter. An identification would be a secondary result, and I don't even care for the actual species, if somebody can say with confidence that is is not a known damager.

Answer (score 9):

Looks like a Western Conifer Seed Bug. Or what my family calls a 'stink bug' because they stink as a defensive measure or when squished. It's a pest but not harmful to humans. Just annoying.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_conifer_seed_bug

Comment: Wee call them wood beetles or stink bugs , they have been bad in my area this year.+ I think any unwanted critter is a pest.

Comment: Kiddos can be a pest but not this ugly!  Yikes